# Java Regex decoding treating multiple delimiters as same not working

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

[image]and thank you for your help,

I am trying to get a regex expression to decode a string with either a comma or semi-colon as anchor but I can't seem to get it to work for comma's or both. Please tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong. thanks!

```
^(?<FADECID>\d{6})?(?<MSG>([a-z A-Z 0-9 ()-:]*[;,]{1}+){8,}+)?(?<ANCH>\w*[;,])?(?<TIME>\d{4})?(?<FM>\d{2})?[;,]?(?<CON>.*)$.*
```

inbound type strings to decode  - I need to treat the comma and or semicolon the same.

```
383154VSC    X1;;;;;;;BOTH WASTE DRAIN VLV    NOT CLSD (135MG;35MG);HARD;093502
282151FCMC1  1;;;;;;;FUEL MAIN PUMP1 (121QA1);HARD;093502
732112EEC2B  1;;;;;;;FMU(E2-4071KS)WRG:EEC  J12 TO FMV LVDT POS,HARD;
383154VSC    X1,,,,,,,BOTH WASTE DRAIN VLV    NOT CLSD (135MG,35MG),HARD,093502
282151FCMC1  1,,,,,,,FUEL MAIN PUMP1 (121QA1);HARD;093502
732112EEC2B  1,,,,,,,FMU(E2-4071KS)WRG:EEC  J12 TO FMV LVDT POS,HARD,
383154VSC    X1,,,,,,,BOTH WASTE DRAIN VLV    NOT CLSD (135MG;35MG);HARD;093502
282151FCMC1  1;;;;;;;FUEL MAIN PUMP1 (121QA1),HARD,093502
732112EEC2B  1,,,,,,,FMU(E2-4071KS)WRG:EEC  J12 TO FMV LVDT POS;HARD;
```

This string has the possibility to contain mulitple text [;,] separated messages.

```
ABC;DEF;;HIJ;NNN;JJJ;XXX;EEX;HARD;
```

This manages that - (?([a-z A-Z 0-9 ()-:]*[;,]{1}+){8,}+)?
but it doesn't observe commas?

This works for ; but not for comma or both, my problem is that it can be both a semi-colon or a comma?
if I make the regex only comma, it works for comma strings, I know i'm missing a quantifier or something like.

```
                            if ( null != MORE && ! MORE.isEmpty() ) {

                                while ( null != MORE && ! MORE.isEmpty() || MORE.trim().equals("EOR")) {

                                    LOG.info("MORE CONTINUE: " + MORE);
                                    if ( MORE.trim().equals("EOR") ) {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    String patternMoreString = "^(?<FADECID>\\d{6})?(?<MSG>([a-z A-Z 0-9 ()-:()]*[;,]{1}+){8,}+)+?(?<ANCH>\\w*[;,])?(?<TIME>\\d{4})?(?<FM>\\d{2})?[;,]?(?<CON>.*)$.*";
                                    Pattern patternMore = Pattern.compile(patternMoreString, Pattern.DOTALL);
                                    Matcher matcherMore = patternMore.matcher(MORE);

                                    while ( matcherMore.find() ) {

                                        MORE = matcherMore.group("CON");

                                        summary.setReportId("FLR");
                                        summary.setAreg(Areg);
                                        summary.setShip(Ship);
                                        summary.setOrig(Orig);
                                        summary.setDest(Dest);
                                        summary.setTimestamp(Ts);
                                        summary.setAta(matcherMore.group("FADECID"));
                                        summary.setTime(matcherMore.group("TIME"));
                                        summary.setFm(matcherMore.group("FM"));
                                        summary.setMsg(matcherMore.group("MSG"));

                                        serviceRecords.add(summary);

                                        LOG.info("*** A330 MPF MORE Record ***");
                                        LOG.info(summary.getReportId());
                                        LOG.info(summary.getAreg());
                                        LOG.info(summary.getShip());
                                        LOG.info(summary.getOrig());
                                        LOG.info(summary.getDest());
                                        LOG.info(summary.getTimestamp());
                                        LOG.info(summary.getAta());
                                        LOG.info(summary.getTime());
                                        LOG.info(summary.getFm());
                                        LOG.info(summary.getMsg());

                                        summary = new A330PostFlightReportRecord();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //---
```

I need for all cases group 2 and if TIME and FM exists.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(?<FADECID>\d{6})(?<MSG>([a-zA-Z0-9() -]*([;,]))+)?(?<ANCH>\w*\4)?(?<TIME>\d{4})?(?<FM>\d{2})?\4?(?<CON>.*)$`  https://regex101.com/r/RYb92S/1/

Comment: Please edit to show the desired result for your example. You should always do that when you give an example.

Comment: Notice the @Thefourthbird rightly removed '?' at the end of `(?<FADECID>\d{6})?`. If the question mark is present and "My dog has fleas " is added to the beginning of the string, nothing will be captured in the capture group `FACECID` and the following will be captured in the `MSG` capture group: `"My dog has fleas 383154VSC...(135MG;35MG)"`.

Comment: If you provide some java code, it will be easier for others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks !  hey, how does that \4 work?  I've not used or seen that before.  thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a capturing group and a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) using the number of that group to get consistent delimiters.

In this case the capturing group is `([;,])` which is the fourth group denoted by `\4` matching either `;` or `,`

If you only need *group 2 and if TIME and FM* you can omit group *ANCH*

```
^(?<FADECID>\d{6})(?<MSG>([a-zA-Z0-9() -]*([;,])){7,})(?<TIME>\d{4})?(?<FM>\d{2})?\4?(?<CON>.*)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?<FADECID>\d{6})` Named group `FADECID`, match 6 digits
- `(?<MSG>` Named group `MSG`

  - `(` Capture **group 3**

    - `[a-zA-Z0-9() -]*` Match 0+ times any of the lister
    - `([;,])` Capture **group 4**, used as backreference to get consistent delimiters
  - `){7,}` Close group and repeat 7+ times
- `)` Close group `MSG`
- `(?<TIME>\d{4})?` Optional named group `TIME`, match 4 digits
- `(?<FM>\d{2})?` Optional named group `FM`, match 2 digits
- `\4?` Optional backreference to capture group 4
- `(?<CON>.*)` Named group `CON` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yGlmT1/1)

Note that group 3 the capture group itself is repeated, giving you the last value of the iteration, which will be `HARD`

Comment: THANK YOU !!! Appreciated!  I like the back references, thank you for explaining and your help. Excellent.